# Input don't be defined in def function?

Tags: python-3.x

I learn python and I'm to def function.
I try to make a very simply login system just for testing, but I have and error and I don't understand why

Like:

```
def test ():
  User=input("user ?")
  Password=input("password ?")
test()
while True:
  if User=="juu" and Password=="sushi":
    print("welcome")
    break
  else:
    print("sorry but try again")
    test()
```

`
The error message say: if User=="juu" and Password=="sushi": NameError: name 'User' is not defined. Did you mean:'super'?

I have make a mistake ?

Comment: User is a local variable, won’t be accessible outside function body.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is [variable scope](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp): when you define `User` in the test function and run the function, the `User` variable will be stored in the local scope of the function, and therefore will not be accessible from the rest of your code. To fix this, you can return the `User` and `Password` variables to access them later:

```
def test():
    User=input("user ?")
    Password=input("password ?")
    return User, Password
User, Password = test()
while True:
    if User=="juu" and Password=="sushi":
        print("welcome")
        break
    else:
        print("sorry but try again")
        User, Password = test()
```

Comment: Thanks you for your explication it help me :]